# Why is TIMESTAMP fractional seconds off by .001 when exported from DB2 to MSSQL data type DATE, DATETIME, TIMESTAMP not as VARCHAR()

Tags: sql-server, ssis, db2, pentaho-spoon

When I export `TIMESTAMP` data type from DB2 to SQL Server data types `DATE`, `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` the fractional time is off by .001. If I export as data type `VARCHAR()` I get the correct data. Is there an explanation and/or solution for this?

I have exported through SSIS and PENTAHO.

DB2 2021-10-20-21.31.41.138000

SQL Server 2021-10-20 21:31:41.137

Thank you in advance

Comment: The official documentation (which should be your first port of call) for SQL Server `datetime` explains this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result you have is completely expected.

`datetime` is accurate to 1/300th of a second. The closest you can get to `2021-10-20-21.31.41.138000` in a `datetime` is `2021-10-20T21:31:41.136666666666~` which is represented on screen as `2021-10-20 21:31:41.137` (as the displayed value is accurate to 3 digits, and rounded).

If you want the value to be accurate to 1/100000 of a second, use a `datetime2(6)`, which could accurately store the value `2021-10-20T21:31:41.138000`.